# A method where the parameter list is 2 of the same word (name of primitive types)

Tags: java, string, methods, parameters

Saw a code similar to this in my school project's guide. Why is the parameter (String String)? What does this mean. For all I know only variables function etc goes into the parameters list.

```
public static void print (String String) {
    // executable statements
    
  }
```

Comment: That second `String` is just the name the parameter. Whoever wrote the code decided to call that parameter "`String`", which is the same name as its type. This is _allowed_ by the compiler, but as you have experienced, this is also very confusing, and you should not do this.

Comment: It is also worth noting that String is not a primitive type.

Comment: @Sweeper I have always wondered _why_ was this allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to answer your question while providing some background knowledge.

When writing a method in Java, we need to declare the expected arguments inside the method signature. The method signature refers to the method name and its expected argument list and in this scenario, it is : `print (String String)`

Any argument we expect into a method in Java should contain 2 parts (not just a variable name):

- **Argument type**
- **Argument name**

The **Argument type** could be any valid Java data type. There are 2 main data types as follows.

- Primitive data types - byte,short,int,long,float,double,boolean,char
- Non-primitive data types - **String**, Arrays, etc.

So the first **String** word you have in your method signature refers to the expected Java Data Type for the first argument.

The next is the **Argument name**. This will be used inside the method to refer to the specific value passed. In your method signature, the second **string** word refers to the argument name that the method wishes to hold the variable. This can be any name you want, but other than:

1. another argument name in the same argument list
2. any variable name local to the method (used inside the same method body)
3. keywords reserved in Java

To be more precise, in Java, we cannot declare only the argument name in a method, like `print(string)`.
We need to declare both the data type and the argument's name for each argument we expect.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yeah I know about method parameters list, it's just usually we do - AccessModifer ReturnType <identifier> (VariableType Variable Name), like public void addSum(int a, int b). This was confusing because it seemed like they were doing (VariableType VariableType). So, to clarify, the second "String" in the parameters list is just a name? An identifier? I know Strings aren't variables they're more like an object so this (String String) is just a normal (String <identifier>) ? And String isn't a reserved keyword in java? Then can we do (int int)? Or is that illegal

Comment: @kai You can do (String String) but not (int int) because int is a reserved keyword in Java, and String is not.  This is because int is a primitive type, and String is just a class in the Java library that happens to provide a convenient way to represent a string of characters.  Internally, most String class implementations store the string as an array of char primitives.

Comment: @Kai, as the above answer mentions String is not a reserved keyword in Java, but int is reserved; therefore: print(int int) would cause errors. 

So, to answer your exact question,  the second "string" in the parameters list is just the name/ identifier.